# How to stop selenium from printing webdriver-manager messages in python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Each time that I initiate a new webdriver the following text is written to the console:

```
[WDM] - ====== WebDriver manager ======
[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 102.0.5005
[WDM] - Get LATEST chromedriver version for 102.0.5005 google-chrome
[WDM] - Driver [C:\Users\klaas\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\102.0.5005.61\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
```

My goal was to stop selenium from printing this message to the console. Stack Overflow threads with similar topics to this one showed two options that did not work for me. The first one is:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

and the second one is:

```
import logging
from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import LOGGER

LOGGER.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Both of these solutions did work for some others but not for me. Is there some other way to stop selenium from printing webdriver messages?

**Solution:**
As suggested by [MohitC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1330355/mohitc) the following code prevented the webdriver-manager messages to be printed:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('WDM').setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) logs. You can either uninstall it if you are not using or disable logging as below

```
import os
os.environ['WDM_LOG'] = "false"
```

You can also try

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('WDM').setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I tried implementing your solution but the webdriver-manager messages where still printed to the console. Do you have an idea for how this is possible?

Comment: Try other soltiuon I gave

Comment: Thank you so mutch, your second option did the trick! If i could upvote you comment I would but because of my low credit score I am not able to yet.